# why is my if else statement returning the wrong result?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am new to Python and automation.
Our site has a countdown to Friday at the top of the page. I am attempting to find that element and verify it shows the correct number and text depending on the day.

Here is my code (It is defaulting to the counter is incorrect for Tuesday -even though it's Tuesday). So I added print statements to see what data it was picking up, and the number and the text is correct, even though it's listing the number first?

```
if dt.datetime.today().weekday() == 0:
    countdown_text = driver.find_element_by_class_name("friday-text").text
    countdown_number  = driver.find_element_by_class_name("count")
    if countdown_text == " days until #friday" and countdown_number == '4':
        print("Friday Counter is correct. It's Monday - unfortunately.")
    else:
        print("Friday Counter is incorrect for Monday.")

elif dt.datetime.today().weekday() == 1:
    countdown_text = driver.find_element_by_class_name("friday-text").text
    print(countdown_text)
    countdown_number  = driver.find_element_by_class_name("count")
    print(countdown_number)
    if countdown_text == "DAYS UNTIL #FRIDAY" or countdown_number == 3:
            print("Friday Counter is correct. It's Tuesday.")
    else:
        print("Friday Counter is incorrect for Tuesday.")
```

Here is my output.

```
3
DAYS UNTIL #FIREBALLFRIDAY
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="9ee10b8bab4a7522f7e601d07d077e90", element="903e625a-5552-4500-a7fe-a7efca90666c")>
Fireball Friday Counter is incorrect for Tuesday.
```

Comment: `countdown_number` is a DOM element, not a number.

Comment: If you add `.text` to the assignment, it will be a string, not a number.

Comment: Why do you use `and` in the first block, but `or` in the second block. And the first one looks for a lowercase `#friday`, the second one looks for uppercase `#FRIDAY`.

Comment: So you probably want `countdown_number.text == '3':`

Comment: @barmar im focusing on tuesday right now, and once I get it working I will fix the first block to match. as far as using or I was trying to isolate if one of the variables was working and the other wasn't. as for uppercase/lowercase, the element in the html is lowercase, and the css has text transform, so the screen shows uppercase I've tried both with no avail. Added .text to countdown number, output is now 3
DAYS UNTIL #FIREBALLFRIDAY
3
Fireball Friday Counter is incorrect for Tuesday. so not sure where that first/extra 3 is coming from

Comment: The first 3 is coming from `print(countdown_number)`

Comment: All your `if` blocks should be essentially the same, just the expected `countdown_number` changes. And I think it's always just `4 - dt.datetime.today().weekday()`

Answer (score 0):

Got it. I commented out the print countdown_number to see if I could isolate the extra 3, and found that the countdown_text was feeding me the number and the text on two separate lines. so I changed my expected text and received the correct response.

```
elif dt.datetime.today().weekday() == 1:
    countdown_text = driver.find_element_by_class_name("friday-text").text
    print(countdown_text)
    countdown_number  = driver.find_element_by_class_name("count").text
    #print(countdown_number)
    if countdown_text == "3 \nDAYS UNTIL #FRIDAY" or countdown_number == '3':
            print("Friday Counter is correct. It's Tuesday.")
    else:
        print("Friday Counter is incorrect for Tuesday.")
```

output:

```
3
DAYS UNTIL #FIREBALLFRIDAY
Fireball Friday Counter is correct. It's Tuesday.
```

So looks like I can get rid of the coundown number parts, and my final code and output will be

```
elif dt.datetime.today().weekday() == 1:
    countdown_text = driver.find_element_by_class_name("fireball-friday-text").text
    if countdown_text == "3\nDAYS UNTIL #FIREBALLFRIDAY":
            print("Fireball Friday Counter is correct. It's Tuesday.")
    else:
        print("Fireball Friday Counter is incorrect for Tuesday.")
```

output

```
Fireball Friday Counter is correct. It's Tuesday.
```